# Using os.scandir to get all txt files in subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-system

I have a parent dir that has X children dirs each with Y txt files. I want to list all txt files. Is there a way to simplify this?

```
for entry in os.scandir(DIR): 
        for subentry in os.scandir(entry.path):
            if subentry.is_dir():
                for file in os.scandir(subentry.path):
                    if file.is_file() and file.name.endswith("txt"):
                        print(file.name)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways to easily achieve this. The first one is what [@Ludisposed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/140549/ludisposed) [suggested in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186699/using-os-scandir-to-get-all-txt-files-in-subfolders#comment356201_186699), [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). It can also recurse down into subdirectories with `**` (in Python 3):

```
import glob

def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    return glob.iglob(f"{base_dir}/**/*.txt", recursive=True)
```

Or, if you are using Windows, which uses different delimiters for paths:

```
def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    return glob.iglob(rf"{base_dir}\**\*.txt", recursive=True)
```

The other one is basically what [@Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) suggested, [also in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186699/using-os-scandir-to-get-all-txt-files-in-subfolders#comment356206_186699), make this a fully recursive function:

```
def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    for entry in os.scandir(base_dir):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith(".txt"):
            yield entry.name
        elif entry.is_dir():
            yield from get_txt_files(entry.path)
        else:
            print(f"Neither a file, nor a dir: {entry.path}")
```

Both functions return iterators. You can print all names with a simple `for` loop:

```
for name in get_txt_files("foo"):
    print(name)
```

If your directory `X` also contains txt files, they will be yielded from these functions. You can avoid this with `glob` by making the depth level explicit:

```
def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    return glob.iglob(f"{base_dir}/*/*.txt")
```

A third, very similar, way is to use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) (Python 3 only), which also has a `glob` method (that directly returns an iterator). This way you can be sure that this works both on UNIX and Windows:

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    return Path(base_dir).glob("*/*.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I'll go with iglob since there is only one level of depth and it's shorter and easier to read

Comment: @Julio Note that if you are using Windows, it should be `rf"{base_dir}\**\*.txt"`, though. For this reason I would recommend the `pathlib.Path` way.

Comment: I see, I'll give Path a go then.